# Template Caching - Blank Page

Tags: templates, cache, caching

I am running into an odd error with a new EE site I am coding. I tried to turn on the template caching. When I load the page on the front-end website it works the first time but becomes blank on reload. e.g. First Load (http://cl.ly/image/1l27232q1V04) vs Second Load (http://cl.ly/image/0e452626213g). Here is the homepage (http://cl.ly/code/2g1p3f0i3z04) and wrapper (http://cl.ly/code/0V2f2C1f0W3J) template code. Any ideas why I am getting a blank load when trying to use template caching?

I am using EE Core 2.6.0. The main plugins I am using are stash, switchee, ifelse, structure, wygwam, matrix, playa, calendar, freebie, imageSizer & assetLinker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the stash saves the values of variables on the moment of parsing, you can't cache the templates, except on Stash itself.

For example, on the first template, you set the variable "content":

```
{exp:stash:set name='content'}
    <div class='aside adoption-info'>
    (...)
{/exp:stash:set}
```

If the page is cached, this code isn't evaluated anymore. On the wrapper template, the variable "content" will be empty.

```
{exp:stash:get name='content'}
```

Even if you set both templates to cache, each one will have its own cache file that you be put together on a really later stage of parsing.

Personally, I guess your code is too complex, but I didn't look at it enough to say for sure. Try to make it simpler or to just use the cache of Stash.